# How do you force Gradle to overwrite a resource file in a custom WAR task?

Tags: java, gradle, copy

i create a war task to overwrite src/main/resources with src/release/resources:

```
task warRelease(type: War) {
    webInf {
        from 'src/release/resources'
        into 'classes'
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.WARN
}
```

unexpected there are two database.properties in the war file

```
$ jar tf build/libs/project.war | grep database
WEB-INF/classes/database.properties
WEB-INF/classes/database.properties
```

According to [this](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1264),

> As of Gradle 0.9.1, the Copy task always overwrites files. The other
>   strategies are not supported yet.

gradle -v

```
Gradle 2.14.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-07-18 06:38:37 UTC
Revision:     d9e2113d9fb05a5caabba61798bdb8dfdca83719

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_102 (Oracle Corporation 25.102-b14)
OS:           Linux 4.7.2-1-ARCH amd64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The War task only extends the AbstractCopy task. The link is directly talking about a CopyTask. You normally use the [setDuplicatesStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#setDuplicatesStrategy(org.gradle.api.file.DuplicatesStrategy)) API to have a task exclude duplicate files. The trick is the secondary files are always excluded, and you can't override it (I think) for a WAR task.

The `src/main/resources` files are always included by default in the WAR task. I have not found a way to change the ordering of the default includes. The next best option is to directly exclude the replaced file from the WAR:

```
task warRelease(type: War) {
   classifier 'release'
   webInf {
      from 'src/main/release'
      into 'classes/'
   }
   rootSpec.filesMatching(/database.properties/) { details ->
      if (details.file.path =~ "build/resources/main/"){
         details.exclude()
      }
   }
}
```

You may wonder why the excluded file is coming from the path `build/resources/main/`. That is because the `processResources` task will copy all of the sourceSets' resource files to this location before they are included into the WAR.

Comment: this will exclude 'src/release' not the 'src/main'

Answer (score 0):

The `build.gradle` file you specified does indeed write a WARN message (re: duplicates) to the console as one would suspect.

In order for the WAR file to prefer `src/release/resources/database.properties` over `src/main/resources/database.properties`, consider this:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

task warRelease(type: War) {
    webInf {
        exclude 'src/main/resources/database.properties'
        from 'src/release/resources'
        into 'classes'
    }
}
```

Comment: this exclude nothing, if it works it will exclude the file in `from 'src/release/resources'`