# Gradle: Exclude file from resourses and add it from different folder

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle

I am trying to build a jar file with Gradle.
I have some resource files (like log4j2 and persistent.xml) into the src/main/resources
that I want to exclude when I was built the jar, on contrary I have the same files (with different content in a project directory) and I want to copy these files rather than the src/main/resource files.

Into my gradle.build

```
from jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    // The parent folder is: src/main/resources for the (1) and (2)
    exclude('META-INF/persistence.xml') // (1)
    exclude('log4j2.xml') // (2)
  
    from('distributions/persistence.xml'){ // (3)
        into 'META-INF'
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [TEST_PARAM: 'tmp_value1'])
    }
    
    from('distributions/log4j2.xml') { // (4)
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [TEST_PARAM: 'tmp_value1'])
    }
}
```

So I exclude the two files manually (1), (2), and then I added (3), (4).
When I extract the jar, I can find the persistence.xml but not the log4j2.xml.

**And my question is, why does this happen?**

### (PS)

If i replace the (1), (2) with

```
processResources.exclude('*')
```

Into jar are placed both the persistence.xml but not the log4j2.xml.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to [this documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files): *Any exclusion pattern overrides any inclusions, so if a file or directory matches at least one exclusion pattern, it won’t be included, regardless of the inclusion patterns.*

It seems like the behavior you observe is caused by how file exclusion is handled by gradle. The way you did it works for the files copied to a subfolder in jar file. For some reason it does not work for files copied to the root folder of jar file.

You can achieve what you want with this configuration:

```
jar {
  from('distributions') {
    include("**/*.xml")
  }

  eachFile {
    if (it.file.path =~ "build/resources/main/") {
      // exclude resources copied from build/resources/main/
      it.exclude()
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the project tree I used since mine can be different from the project you are working on:

```
├── build.gradle
├── distributions
│   ├── META-INF
│   │   └── persistence.xml
│   └── log4j2.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── Main.java
        └── resources
            ├── META-INF
            │   └── persistence.xml
            └── log4j2.xml
```

This solution is based on these discussions:

1. https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-override-where-some-files-are-written-to-in-the-jar-file/5282
2. [How do you force Gradle to overwrite a resource file in a custom WAR task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424647/how-do-you-force-gradle-to-overwrite-a-resource-file-in-a-custom-war-task)

Comment: A addition: The "build/resources/main/" path is related to the java plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54006198/what-does-gradle-do-with-the-files-which-are-located-in-src-main-resources-dire